# Change iframe text to other language

Tags: php, javascript

i have an iframe :
http://www.vantagewire.com/quotes_clients.php?ticker=THG:CA&chscale=1m&stylesheet=http://www.vantagewire.com/_resources/app/general/quotetab_chart_small_hosted.css

i would like to embed this to a site but what i encounter is some users see it in french language other in english.

i would like to make control of the iframe output in a code like this:

```
 if(language==en){
   iframe here which is english form
 }
 if(language==fr){
   iframe here which is french form
 }
```

or any idea how to make the link above make to french and en that i can control ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any API that translates the text into fr or en?

Comment: No, i don't have one. All have is an iframe code above with it's source.

Comment: Google Translate has an API: https://developers.google.com/translate/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a little bit tricky, because the language is sent by the browser header and the browser get first a snippet that includes another request to the server. And we have to manipulate the header of this "inner" request.

For this you need the curl-extension for PHP, otherwise it would be more difficult.

```
<?php
function curlLang($url, $lang = 'en') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language:' . $lang . ';q=0.5'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
$r = (string) $_GET['r'];
if ($r == '') {
    $iframe = curlLang('http://www.vantagewire.com/quotes_clients.php?ticker=THG:CA&chscale=1m&stylesheet=http://www.vantagewire.com/_resources/app/general/quotetab_chart_small_hosted.css');
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?r=';
    $newIframe = preg_replace('~<script.*src="(.*)".*</script>~', '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $self . '$1"></script>', $iframe);
    echo $newIframe;
} else {
    echo curlLang($r);
}
```